# Using Google Drive PHP API to read and write Google Doc tables

Tags: google-drive-api, google-sheets-api

I'm thinking about the followin scenario:

My PHP application push some integers into a google doc table which calculates with this and saves the result of this operations at the end of the table. my php application finally reads the result and displays it on the website.

Is this possible with the Google Drive PHP API?

I found the following:
http://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/
https://developers.google.com/drive/
https://developers.google.com/drive/examples/php#setting_up_this_sample_application

But I'm not sure if this would be possible at all? Are there any example applications or scripts in order to read and write google doc tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Spreadsheets API to programmatically read and write to a Google Spreadsheet:

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/

Comment: The API was written for .NET and JAVA, isn't it?

Comment: You can use any language, there are also client libraries for Python, PHP and other languages. The PHP one is part of the Zend Framework